# Google Oauth 2.0 scope issue

Tags: google-oauth, google-drive-api

I want to access the Google Drive using the OAuth 2.0 for Devices to upload files. So I set the scope variable as `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` and I have  enabled the apis on google developer console.

My Request

```
 POST /o/oauth2/device/code HTTP/1.1
 Host: accounts.google.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
client_id=3146639059-qvroaqrtit609qaknv8anvdn2umus01q.apps.googleusercontent.com & scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
```

But what I am getting in response is

```
{
  "error" : "invalid_scope",
  "error_description" : "Not authorized to request the scopes: [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive]",
  "error_uri" : "http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html"
}
```

Instead of  `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` if I use `email`

as scope its working fine.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: did you enable drive api and drive sdk

Comment: ya I have enabled drive api and drive sdk

Comment: paste the full http request and response into your question. Is this an apps domain user?

Answer (score 0):

You have to post the email address that you get from developer console not the client Id, and you have to authorize the client id on your domaine (Cpanel) for the drive scope.

Comment: I couldn't find any email address in  google  developer console. Where I  can supposed to find the email address?.Can you provide the step by step guide if possible.Thanks